# Why doesn't the value of my variable change even though I passed by reference

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

char toupper(char& letter){
    switch(letter){
        case 'a':
            return 'A';
            break;
        case 'b':
            return 'B';
            break;
        case 'c':
            return 'C';
            break;
        default:
            return letter;
        }
}

int main()
{

char labRat = 'a';
std::cout << toupper(labRat) << std::endl;
std::cout << labRat;

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A
a
```

The value of my variable doesn't change even though I passed it to my function by reference. Why isn't my second output line `A`?

Comment: You don't change it and don't even invoke any kind of UB, so why should it change?

Comment: Can you explain why you expect it to change?

Comment: I think you should use the toupper() function. It is defined in <cctype> header file. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/

Comment: @csg I know the toupper() function; what am I trying to do is code the toupper() function from scratch.

Comment: That's a weird reason but anyway. Do this: `letter = 'A'; return letter;`

Comment: No, do one or the other. Having a return and output parameter both be the same is just bad.

Comment: @JayYay You're going about it in a horribly inefficient manner. A single if block is all you need if you are just doing ASCII. If not, I believe `<locale>` has better versions of a lot of `<cctype>` functions.

Comment: Writing a *portable* `toupper` function is a pain in the neck. This is one reason why it's a C++ standard library function - your standard library implementation is allowed to make assumptions about the target platform. In that case it is allowed to subtract 32 from a lower-case letter if the platform has ASCII encoded characters.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but in that `switch` statement, the cases that execute a `return` don't need a `break`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do indeed pass `labRat` by reference to the function, but you don't change the value of `letter` (which refers to `labRat` in the caller) in `toupper`.

It's not to everyone's taste<sup>1</sup>, but code like

```
return letter = 'A';
```

is one way of returning the value as well as setting the reference value. The *assignment* expression `letter = 'A'` has the value `'A'` and type `char`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Some software houses ban assignments in `return` statements as they can be unclear. It's also easy to misread them as `return letter == 'A';`.

Comment: Worked for a company that banned everything in a return statement. They'd had a problem with a compiler botching 64 bit math in a return statement and kind-of over compensated.

Comment: @user4581301: Funny how one house bans one thing and another bans another. I ban `std::vector`'s `[]` operator unless it can be demonstrated that it has a material performance benefit.

Answer (score 3):

See improved code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    char toupper(char& letter){
        switch(letter){
            case 'a':
                letter = 'A';
                // return 'A';
                break;
            case 'b':
               letter = 'B';
                // return 'B';
                break;
            case 'c':
               letter = 'C';
                // return 'C';
                break;
            default:
                return letter;
            }
            
            return letter;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
      char labRat = 'a';
      std::cout << toupper(labRat) << std::endl;
      std::cout << labRat;
    
      return 0;
    }
```

You are not `assigning` value to `letter` variable in `toupper` function.

Comment: This is probably more sensible than the way I'd do it. (Although personally I'd remove the `default` case as it's no longer needed.) Have an upvote!

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are not changing the passed character in the ***toupper*** function, you are just returning value.

Comment: A strong answer identifies and explains the problem AND contains a potential solution.